# Simplejson and unity, how to create json from multiple objects?

Tags: c#, json, simplejson

I'm trying to do those things :

1- read a json

2- select some data inside the json

3- generate a new json

I'm stuck at 3) I try to generate a json from objects created by a for loop. Also if you have any documentation about simplejson it would be appreciated because i'm a bit lost.

```
public class CollectCards : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string set;
    public string Rid;
    public string Rname;
    public string Rset;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start ()
    {
        string str = Read ();
        JSONNode cardData = JSON.Parse (str);
        string[] setlist = new string[] {
            "Basic",
            "Advanced",
            "Expert"
        };
        for (int j=0; j<setlist.Length; j++) {
            set = setlist [j];
            for (int i =0; i<cardData[set].Count; i++) {
                Rid = cardData [set] [i] ["id"].Value;
                Rname = cardData [set] [i] ["name"].Value;
                Rset = setlist [j];
                Card carte = new Card (Rid, Rname,Rset);
                I'M STUCK HERE;   
            }
        }
    }
    string Read()
    {
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader (Application.dataPath + "/Resources/Cards.json");
        string content = sr.ReadToEnd ();
        sr.Close();
        return content;
    } 
}

public class Card {
    public string id;
    public string name;
    public string cardset;

    public Card(string id, string name, string cardset)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.cardset=cardset;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you getting an error message?

Comment: No everything is working fine but I don't know the code to write a Json from the several "Card carte" created.